# Solve the PDE $uu_t + uu_x = 0$ using an appropriate substitution

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We are supposed to solve the initial value problem:

$uu_t + uu_x = 0$

$u(x,0) = f(x)$

I genuinely have no idea how to find an appropriate substitution to make this linear. Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$uu_t+uu_x=0$$
Substitution : $\quad v(x,t)=(u(x,t))^2 \qquad\implies\quad\begin{cases} v_x=2uu_x \\v_t=2uu_t\end{cases}$
$$v_x+v_t=0$$
Well known general solution : $\qquad v(x,t)=F(x-t) \qquad$

with any differentiable function $F(X)$ and $X=x-t$.

Condition : $\quad u(x,0)=f(x)\quad$ where $f(x)$ is a given function.

$v(x,0)=(u(x,0))^2=(f(x))^2 \quad\implies\quad F(x-0)=(f(x))^2$

Thus $F(X)$ is determined : $\quad F(X)=(f(X))^2$

Putting $F(X)=(f(x))^2$ into $v(x,t)=F(x-t)$ with $X=x-t$ leads to :
$$v(x,t)=(f(x-t))^2$$

$$u(x,t)=f(x-t)$$

NOTE :

In the present case, the method with substitution is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

More simply :
$$uu_t+uu_x=(u_t+u_x)u=0 \quad\implies\quad u=0 \quad\text{or}\quad (u_t+u_x)=0$$
The condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ exclues the case $u(x,t)=0$ except if $f(x)=0$ which is not the case in general.

So, you just have to solve $u_t+u_x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $ 2f f' = (f^2)'$. The substitution should then be clear.

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't seem to understand...

Comment: @helpneeded You're going to have to ask for specifics, please add what you have tried.

Comment: I wish i could say i as able to try something. I really don't see how this information can be used to make the substitution. I can't seem to make the link.

Comment: @helpneeded Its okay to be wrong, please give me anything. What do you suppose my hint would be suggesting you write?

Comment: $2vv_t = (v^2)'$? So because of that, we can replace $uu_t$ with $(v^2)_t$?

Comment: @helpneeded how does the $t$ derivative relate to $'$?

Comment: I really don't know the answer to that question, i though that you could replace $'$ with $t$ like I did above

Comment: the $'$ notation is only for functions of one variable. It should be $2uu_t = (u^2)_t$ (not sure what $v$ is). What else can you do?

Comment: Oh i just added the $v$ to make it appear like I made a substitution. Purely arbitrary. Also, I'm guessing the final equation becomes $(u^2)_t + (u^2)_x = 0$.

Comment: @helpneeded Its not a substitution, unless you count $v=u$ as a substitution, since there is the exact equality $2uu_t = (u^2)_t$. Good that you noticed it doesn't help. There is another term in your PDE, what about it?

Comment: @helpneeded yeah thats it. It should look familliar.

Comment: It kind of looks like Burger's equation. But i really don't understand how this substitution helps solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70408/discussion-between-calvin-khor-and-helpneeded).